# MongoDB map reduce count giving more results than a query

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection `users` in Mongo and I execute this map reduce which I believe is the equivalent of a COUNT(*) GROUP BY `origin`:

```
> m = function() { for (i in this.membership) {
... emit( this.membership[i].platform_profile.origin, 1 );
... }  }
function () {
    for (i in this.membership) {
        emit(this.membership[i].platform_profile.origin, 1);
    }
}
> r = function( id, values ) { var result = 0; 
... for ( var i = 0; i < values.length; i ++ ) { result += values[i];  }
... return result; }
function (id, values) {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        result += values[i];
    }
    return result;
}
> db.users.mapReduce(m, r, {out : { inline: 1}});
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "value" : 15
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "value" : 449
        },
    ...
}
```

But if I try to count how many documents have this field set to a specific value like `1`, I get fewer results:

> db.users.count({"membership.platform_profile.origin": 1});

```
424
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show your json object?

Comment: Here it is an example of row: http://pastebin.com/GhtJr9ES

Answer (score 2):

Are your count queries using a sparse index by any chance? My only guess there would be if some other query criteria resulted in documents absent from from index to be ignored from the count.

I recreated your schema with some fixture data and the results between map/reduce and simple count queries are in agreement:

```
db.users.drop();

var map = function() {
    for (i in this.membership) {
        emit(this.membership[i].platform_profile.origin, 1);
    }
};

var reduce = function(id, values ) {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        result += values[i];
    }
    return result;
}

var origins = {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c", 4: "d"};

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    var membership = [];

    for (var o in origins) {
        if (0 == i % o) {
            membership.push({ platform_profile: { origin: origins[o] }});
        }
    }

    db.users.save({ membership: membership });
}

db.users.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: {inline: 1}}).results.forEach(function(result){
    print(result["_id"] + ": " + result["value"]);
});

for (var o in origins) {
    print(origins[o] + ": " + db.users.count({"membership.platform_profile.origin": origins[o]}));
}
```

Here's the output:

```
$ mongo --quiet mr_count.js 
a: 1000
b: 500
c: 334
d: 250
a: 1000
b: 500
c: 334
d: 250
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following map/reduce for the equivalent of `COUNT(*) GROUP BY origin`

Map/Reduce Functions :

```
map = function() {
    if(!this.membership) return;

    for (i in this.membership) {
        if(!this.membership[i].platform_profile || !this.membership[i].platform_profile.origin) return;
        emit(this.membership[i].platform_profile.origin, 1);
    }
}

reduce = function(key, values) {
    var count = 0;

    for (v in values) {
        count += values[v];
    }
    return count;
}

result = db.runCommand({
        "mapreduce" : "users", 
        "map" : map,
        "reduce" : reduce,
        "out" : "users_count"
});
```

Comment: The result of the map reduce is already correct; but find() is not consistent with it as it finds fewer results for the various origins.

Comment: what you mean by fewer results? Didn't it emit all the documents?

Comment: The map reduce works correctly, but doing a db.users.find() or db.users.count() on the original table doesn't find all documents - for example 424 instead of 449 for origin=1.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I replaced `x.length by Array.sum(x)` in the reduce function (assuming you emit 1 in the map function) and it works. I agree `x.length` should work too, but I cannot explain why it does not.